# The same layout mutliple times in one layout not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a little problem with my app. I am adding the **same layout 11 times** to my **main layout** and here I am adding text to them. The Problem is, that **no text shows** up at all. Sorry for my not perfect english. :D

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("username", username);
params.put("pass", password);
JSONObject json = parser.makeHttpRequest(link to php file, params);

ArrayList<String> stundenList = new ArrayList<>();

int success = json.getInt("success");

if (success == 1) {
    JSONArray stunden = json.getJSONArray("stundenplan");

    for (int i = 0; i < stunden.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = stunden.getJSONObject(i);

        String montag = c.getString("montag");
        String dienstag = c.getString("dienstag");
        String mittwoch = c.getString("mittwoch");
        String donnerstag = c.getString("donnerstag");
        String freitag = c.getString("freitag");

        stundenList.add(montag);
        stundenList.add(dienstag);
        stundenList.add(mittwoch);
        stundenList.add(donnerstag);
        stundenList.add(freitag);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < getRows().size(); i++) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) Karo.main.findViewById(getRows().get(i));
        TextView column1 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column2 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column3 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column4 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column5 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column6 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column7 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column8 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column9 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column10 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
        TextView column11 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);

        column1.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[0]);
        column2.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[1]);
        column3.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[2]);
        column4.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[3]);
        column5.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[4]);
        column6.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[5]);
        column7.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[6]);
        column8.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[7]);
        column9.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[8]);
        column10.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[9]);
        column11.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[10]);
    }
}
```

getRows function:

```
private static List<Integer> getRows() {
    List<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(R.id.stundenplan_montag);
    rows.add(R.id.stundenplan_dienstag);
    rows.add(R.id.stundenplan_mittwoch);
    rows.add(R.id.stundenplan_donnerstag);
    rows.add(R.id.stundenplan_freitag);
    return rows;
}
```

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/verplan"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Karo"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/ViewFlipp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home Text" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include android:id="@+id/stundenplan_montag" layout="@layout/plantextviews"/>
        <include android:id="@+id/stundenplan_dienstag" layout="@layout/plantextviews" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <include android:id="@+id/stundenplan_mittwoch" layout="@layout/plantextviews" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <include android:id="@+id/stundenplan_donnerstag" layout="@layout/plantextviews" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <include android:id="@+id/stundenplan_freitag" layout="@layout/plantextviews" android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

plantextviews layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column2" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column3" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column4" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column5" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column6" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column7" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column8" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column9" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column10" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/column11" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are finding view by id = `R.id.column1` 11 times, but you should find views with ids `R.id.column1`, `R.id.column2`, `R.id.column3` and so on:

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < getRows().size(); i++) {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) Karo.main.findViewById(getRows().get(i));
    TextView column1 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column1);
    TextView column2 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column2);
    TextView column3 = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.column3);
    ...
    ...

    column1.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[0]);
    column2.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[1]);
    column3.setText(stundenList.get(i).split(";")[2]);
    ...
    ...
}
```